# Initialize a huge vector of type vector <int>

Tags: c++

Gurus,
I am trying to initialize a huge vector> but failing with the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc Aborted

Following is the way initialization is done:

```
vector<vector< int >> result(k, vector<int> (prices.size() + 1, 0)) ;
```

Full code:

```
    class Solution {
public:
    int maxProfit(int k, vector<int>& prices) {

        int sz = prices.size();

        vector<vector< int >> result(k, vector<int> (prices.size() + 1, 0)) ;

        return 1;


    }
};

int stringToInteger(string input) {
    return stoi(input);
}

void trimLeftTrailingSpaces(string &input) {
    input.erase(input.begin(), find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](int ch) {
        return !isspace(ch);
    }));
}

void trimRightTrailingSpaces(string &input) {
    input.erase(find_if(input.rbegin(), input.rend(), [](int ch) {
        return !isspace(ch);
    }).base(), input.end());
}

vector<int> stringToIntegerVector(string input) {
    vector<int> output;
    trimLeftTrailingSpaces(input);
    trimRightTrailingSpaces(input);
    input = input.substr(1, input.length() - 2);
    stringstream ss;
    ss.str(input);
    string item;
    char delim = ',';
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        output.push_back(stoi(item));
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        int k = stringToInteger(line);
        getline(cin, line);
        vector<int> prices = stringToIntegerVector(line);

        int ret = Solution().maxProfit(k, prices);

        string out = to_string(ret);
        cout << out << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Following is the input[1](https://text-share.com/view/2481b925) which results in the issue:
https://text-share.com/view/2481b925

Any pointers on the possible issue will help.

Comment: Make sure you have enough RAM as 1000000000 int requires nearly 4G RAM if my calculation was right.

Comment: Not only that, is your program a 64-bit program?  If it's 32-bit, then forget about it.  Allocating 4GB of contiguous RAM for a 64-bit program is usually successful.

Comment: It is possible that you do not have enough memory. Even if you memory, getting a contiguous block of memory for huge data may not be successful. You can use structures that use a linked list instead.

Comment: I just ran a quick test using Visual Studio 2017, and creating a `vector<int> v(1000000000)` works successfully for a 64-bit program.

Comment: Thank you all. I will reorg the code to avoid huge memory need.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Each vector inside the main one will perform its own allocation; there's no requirement here for contiguity.  (There is a large contiguous block needed by just the outer vector, but that's a small fraction of the total memory requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking by `max_size()`. This value typically reflects the theoretical limit on the size of the container.

```
std::vector<int> TestVec;
    std::cout << "Max elements to reserve: " << TestVec.max_size() << std::endl;
```